# HighCharts - applying a formatting function over plot options

Tags: highcharts

I'm new to Highcharts and fairly new to programming in general and am trying to figure out if it's possible to apply a function over a plot option. E.g. where `myFormatter` is the function

```
tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
    pointFormat: 'myFormatter({point.y})'
}
```

If this is not possible, are there any suggestions other than having to reformat the entire dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible, but you can achieve the same result by using `formatter`:

```
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      return `<b>${this.series.name}</b><br>` + myFormatter(this.point.y)
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ce1829oa/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter